# Simulating a roll with a biased dice

Tags: language-agnostic, random, probability

I did a [search](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=die%20plural#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=dice%20biased&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&fp=4fb1180a34b58d1d) but didn't really get any proper hits.  Maybe I used incorrect terms?

What I want to ask about is an algorithm for **simulating a biased role** rather than a standard supposedly-random roll.

*It wouldn't be a problem if you can't give me exact answers (maybe the explanation is lengthy?) but I would appreciate &pointers to material I can read about it.*

What I have in mind is to for example, shift the bias towards the  5, 6 area so that the numbers rolls would have a higher chances of getting a 5 or a 6; that's the sort of problem I'm trying to solve.

**[Update]**

Upon further thought and by inspecting some of the answers, I've realized that what I want to achieve is really the *[Roulette Wheel Selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection)* operator that's used in genetic algorithms since having a larger sector means increasing the odds the ball will land there.  Am I correct with this line of thought?

Comment: Do you want to simulate a biased dice _physically_  or you want to pre-assign probabilities to each outcome? Hint: _physically_ is difficult ...

Comment: Not physically, no; the probabilities are pre-assigned.  I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Incidentally, I believe the relevant search terms include: "how do I sample from a multinomial distribution?" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution#Sampling_from_a_multinomial_distribution

Comment: @dsg: If that's the case, then no wonder I got jack.

Comment: Are you rolling one die, or multiple dice for a total?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard: One die is what I had in mind.

Comment: Then never mind what I was thinking, belisarius gives a good method.

Comment: @Andreas The _Roulette wheel_ is what I proposed. My answer is simpler than your link because I assumed probabilities instead of a fitness parameter, so they sum up 1 by definition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, if your probabilities are {p1,p2, ...,p6}, construct the following helper list:

```
{a1, a2, ... a5} = { p1, p1+p2, p1+p2+p3, p1+p2+p3+p4, p1+p2+p3+p4+p5}
```

Now get a random number X in [0,1]

If

```
        X <= a1  choose 1 as outcome  
   a1 < X <= a2  choose 2 as outcome 
   a2 < X <= a3  choose 3 as outcome  
   a3 < X <= a4  choose 4 as outcome  
   a4 < X <= a5  choose 5 as outcome  
   a5 < X        choose 6 as outcome
```

Or, more efficient pseudocode

```
   if     X > a5 then N=6
   elseif X > a4 then N=5
   elseif X > a3 then N=4
   elseif X > a2 then N=3
   elseif X > a1 then N=2
   else               N=1
```

**Edit**

This is equivalent to the *roulette wheel selection* you mention in your question update as shown in this picture:

[image]

Comment: Generating the helper array adds unnecessary calculations that weights easily address.

Comment: Wrote a java code based on above answer. Please find the code: http://censore.blogspot.in/2014/08/simulate-roll-of-bias-or-weighted-dice.html

Answer (score 2):

Let's say the die is biased towards a 3.

Instead of picking a random entry from an array 1..6 with 6 entries, pick a random entry from an array 1..6, 3, 3.  (8 entries).

Comment: You mean pre-populating the array with the numbers according to their probability.  Isn't that a bit inefficient as regards space?

Comment: There are only six entries.  If it was a 1 million sided die, you would be correct. :)

Comment: It's a good solution if you don't mind being restricted within certain probability values for your dice. If you want arbitrary values you got the problem mentioned by @Andreas

Answer (score 2):

Make a 2 dimensional array of possible values and their weights. Sum up all the weights. Randomly choose a value on the range of 0 to the sum of the weights. 
Now iterate through the array while keeping an accumulator of the weights seen so far. Once this value exceeds your random number, pick the value of the die represented here.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Say you want to have a 1/2 chance of getting a six, and a 1/10 chance of getting any other face. To simulate this, you could generate a random integer `n` in `[1, 2, ... , 10]` , and the outcome would map to six if `n` is in `[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` and map to `n` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

One way that's usually fairly easy is to start with a random number in an expanded range, and break that range up into unequal pieces.

For example, with a perfectly even (six-sided) die, each number should come up 1/6<sup>th</sup> of the time. Let's assume you decide on round percentages -- all the other numbers should come up 16 percent of the time, but 2 should come up 17 percent of the time.

You could do that by generating numbers from 1 to 100. If the number is from 1 to 16, it comes out as a 1. If it's from 17 to 34, it comes out as a 2. If it's from 34 to 50, it comes out as a 3 (and the rest are blocks of 16 apiece).